# Creating a function that takes a list, creates chunks within the list in increasing size starting from 1, and the reverses it

Tags: python

Creating a function that takes a list, creates chunks within the list in increasing size starting from 1, and the reverses it. Should be an inplace solution, without having a return statement.

What I have tried:

```
def backward_chunk(l, size):
start = 0
for end in range(len(l)%size, len(l)+1, size):
    yield l[start:end]
    start = end
```

Example:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> backward_chunk(l, 7)
>>> l
[1, 3, 2, 6, 5, 4, 7]
```

explained:

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] then broken into chunks
[(1), (2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9, 10)] then each chunk is reversed

Comment: Why are you using a generator?

Comment: Anyway, I don't really understand the described behavior.

Comment: Just trying different methods, please correct if it is wrong

Comment: I added an explanation

Comment: You shouldn't just randomly write things. If you decide to use a generator, you need to have some sort of idea about how and why that is supposed to work. For example, a generator function returns a generator object. None of the code in the generator function actually executes when you do `backward_chunk(l, 7)`. So of course, how is it supposed to have modified `l`?

Comment: Got it, i'm still learning

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple loop to do this. I usually don't recommend modifying a list in place (as it changes it for all the places in the code that thought they had the original version). But since you asked:

```py
def rev_chunks_inplace(a):
    j = 1
    for n in range(2, len(a)):
        i, j = j, j + n
        if i >= len(a):
            break
        a[i:j] = a[i:j][::-1]
```

Example:

```py
rev_chunks_inplace(a := list(range(14)))
>>> a
[0, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 9, 8, 7, 6, 13, 12, 11, 10]
```

and on your list

```py
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
rev_chunks_inplace(l)
>>> l
[1, 3, 2, 6, 5, 4, 7]
```

Note: if you are okay with a generator, it will have no side effect on your list, which usually is preferable (one less opportunity to mess something up that will cause hours of debugging). A similar approach can be used:

```py
def irev_chunks(a):
    j = 0
    for n in range(1, len(a) + 1):
        i, j = j, j + n
        if i >= len(a):
            break
        yield from a[i:j][::-1]
```

```py
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> list(irev_chunks(l))
[1, 3, 2, 6, 5, 4, 7]

>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, modifying a list in place when passed to a function is generally not a good idea. But since that's what you're looking for:

1. Start at index 1 (2nd element) since the first one with chunk size 1 doesn't need to be flipped.
2. Chunk size starts at 2 elements and then increments by 1 for each loop
3. Each cunk-sized-slice of the list is assigned that [slice in reverse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/1431750) using `-1` for the step and flipping the start and end indexes (+/- 1)

   - or use the same index but add a `[::-1]` to reverse it
4. The starting index of the next chunk is the current start + current chunksize
5. Repeat until `start` reaches end of the list<sup>*</sup>

```py
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

def flip(lst):
    start = 1
    size = 2  # after the first element, next chunk is size 2
    while start < len(lst):
        lst[start : start + size] = lst[start + size - 1 : start - 1 : -1]
        # or, more readable:
        # lst[start : start + size] = lst[start : start + size][::-1]
        start += size
        size += 1

print(l)
flip(l)
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 3, 2, 6, 5, 4, 7]
```

If after the last chunk, your list has 2 or more elements left, then it will also flip the last chunk, even if the chunk size is less than what the next one should be. For example:

```py
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
flip(l)
print(l)
# [1, 3, 2, 6, 5, 4, 9, 8, 7]  (last 2 chunks are both size 3)
```

<sup>*</sup> If the last chunk which is less than the required chunk size *should not be flipped*, change the loop condition to `while start + size <= len(lst):`, which would give:

```py
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
flip(l)
print(l)
# [1, 3, 2, 6, 5, 4, 7, 8, 9]  (7 8 9 is not flipped)

# and works normally when the next chunk is the right size:
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
flip(l)
print(l)
# [1, 3, 2, 6, 5, 4, 10, 9, 8, 7]  (7 8 9 10 is size 4 which is the correct next chunk size)
```

Edit: And to make it a generator, on the line which does the flipping, instead of assigning it back to the list, put a `yield from`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.count`:

```
import itertools
def get_chunks(d):
   n, d = itertools.count(1), iter(d)
   while any(k:=[next(d, None) for _ in range(next(n))]):
      yield list(filter(None, k))

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
result = [i for j in get_chunks(l) for i in j[::-1]]
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 2, 6, 5, 4, 7]
```